# gensim word2vec entry greater than 1

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm new to NLP and gensim, currently trying to solve some NLP problems with gensim word2vec module. I my current understanding of word2vec, the result vectors/matrix should have all entries between -1 and 1. However, trying a simple one results into a vector which has entries greater than 1. I'm not sure which part is wrong, could anyone give some suggestions, please?

I've used gensim utils.simple_preprocess to generate a list of list of token. The list looks like:

```
[['buffer', 'overflow', 'in', 'client', 'mysql', 'cc', 'in', 'oracle', 'mysql', 'and', 'mariadb', 'before', 'allows', 'remote', 'database', 'servers', 'to', 'cause', 'denial', 'of', 'service', 'crash', 'and', 'possibly', 'execute', 'arbitrary', 'code', 'via', 'long', 'server', 'version', 'string'], ['the', 'xslt', 'component', 'in', 'apache', 'camel', 'before', 'and', 'before', 'allows', 'remote', 'attackers', 'to', 'read', 'arbitrary', 'files', 'and', 'possibly', 'have', 'other', 'unspecified', 'impact', 'via', 'an', 'xml', 'document', 'containing', 'an', 'external', 'entity', 'declaration', 'in', 'conjunction', 'with', 'an', 'entity', 'reference', 'related', 'to', 'an', 'xml', 'external', 'entity', 'xxe', 'issue']]
```

I believe this is the correct input format for gensim word2vec.

```
word2vec = models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=50, window=5, min_count=1, workers=3, sg=1)
vector = word2vec['overflow']
print(vector)
```

I expect the output to be a vector containing probabilities (i.e., all between -1 and 1), but it actually turned out to be the following:

```
[ 0.12800379 -0.7405527  -0.85575     0.25480416 -0.2535793   0.142656
 -0.6361196  -0.13117172  1.1251501   0.5350017   0.05962601 -0.58876884
  0.02858278  0.46106443 -0.22623934  1.6473309   0.5096218  -0.06609935
 -0.70007527  1.0663376  -0.5668168   0.96070313 -1.180383   -0.58649933
 -0.09380565 -0.22683378  0.71361005  0.01779896  0.19778453  0.74370056
 -0.62354785  0.11807996 -0.54997736  0.10106519  0.23364201 -0.11299669
 -0.28960565 -0.54400533  0.10737313  0.3354464  -0.5992898   0.57183135
 -0.67273194  0.6867607   0.2173506   0.15364875  0.7696457  -0.24330224
  0.46414775  0.98163396]
```

You can see there are `1.6473309` and `-1.180383` in the above vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not** the case that individual word-vectors will have all their individual dimensions between `-1.0` and `1.0`.

Nor is it the case that the dimensions should be interpreted as "probabilities".

Rather, the word-vectors are learned such that the internal neural-network becomes as good as possible at predicting words from surrounding words. There's no constraint or normalization during that training forcing the individual dimensions into a restricted range, or making individual dimensions interpretable as nameable qualities.

It is sometimes the case that such vectors are converted, after training, into vectors of normalized unit-length, before comparison to each other. And further, when you request the cosine-similarity between two vectors, the result will always be in the range from `-1.0` to `1.0`. And, before doing the very-common `most_similar()` operation (or similar), the `Word2Vec` class with bulk-unit-normalize vectors & cache the results internally.

But, directly asking for the raw word-vector, as per `model.wv['overflow']`, will return the raw vector with whatever original overall magnitude, and per-dimension values, as came from training. You can request the unit-normed vector instead with:

```
model.wv.word_vec('overflow', use_norm=True)
```

(Separately be aware: testing `Word2Vec` on tiny toy-sized datasets will generally not get useful or realistic results: the algorithm really requires large, varied data to come up with balanced, useful word-vectors. For example, to train-up 50-dimensional vectors, I'd want at least 2,500 unique words in the vocabulary, with dozens of different uses of each word – so a corpus of many tens of thousands of words. And I might also use more than the default `epochs=5`, because that's still a very small corpus.)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on this problem. I've read many relevant tutorials and articles about gensim and word2vec recently, but their explanations are sometimes very different. So, I just wanna double check which one is correct. Is the result matrix of word2vec actually the hidden layer of the training neural network (i.e., one single entry does not have any specific meaning)? And I guess the reason that each vector can be recognized as corresponding to each word is because of the only one entry with value 1 in each input vector?

Comment: In standard word2vec, the individual dimensions of a word's word-vector don't have independent, clearly-describable meanings. (The coordinate-axes don't neatly line-up with human concepts.) Certain cross-cutting directions in the full high-dimensional space may vaguely correlate to human concepts/scales. The individual word-vectors are not typically weights connecting the NN's hidden-layer-to-outputs. Rather, they're an **input** layer, mapping single words to dense vectors. (Essentially: a "projection layer", but actual one-hot vectors are never instantiated - word-keys are just looked-up.)